Efficient Methods for Updating a BERT Sequence Classification Model with New Classes?
I have a problem finding an effective method to update the classifier layer of my text classification model to include new classes. I am working on a classification task involving brand names based on their descriptions, with two columns: 'description' and 'brand.' After the initial training, I need a way to update the model to classify new classes without retraining the entire model, to save resources.
I have attempted to use a BERT model for sequence classification with PEFT (Parameter-Efficient Fine-Tuning), but I am stuck and unsure if this is the best approach. Specifically, I am having trouble adding new classes to an already trained model.
Here is the code I am currently using:
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AdamW, get_scheduler
from peft import LoraConfig
import torch
from torch import nn
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=len(set(custom_dataset2.labels)))

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type=peft.TaskType.SEQ_CLS, # Type of task: sequence classification
    r=4,                             # Rank of the low-rank adaptation matrices
    lora_alpha=32,                   # Scaling factor for low-rank matrices
    lora_dropout=0.1,                # Dropout probability for low-rank matrices
)

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)
num_epochs = 30
total_steps = num_epochs * len(data_loader2)
lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
    "linear",
    optimizer=optimizer,
    num_warmup_steps=0,
    num_training_steps=total_steps
)

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)

model.train()

progress_bar = tqdm(range(total_steps))
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    losses = []
    correct_predictions = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(data_loader2):
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"].to(device)
        labels = batch["labels"].to(device)

        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)

        logits = outputs.logits
        predictions = logits.argmax(dim=1)
        loss = outputs.loss
        losses.append(loss.item())

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        progress_bar.update(1)
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Step [{i+1}/{total_steps}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

    correct_predictions += torch.sum(predictions == labels)
    train_acc = correct_predictions.double() / len(data_loader1.dataset)
    train_loss = np.mean(losses)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Train accuracy: {train_acc:.4f}, Train loss: {train_loss:.4f}")

# This part of the code is where I need help:
model.classifier = nn.Linear(model.bert.config.hidden_size, 100)

When I attempt to increase the number of classes and train the adapter again instead of retraining the model, I always encounter the following error:
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 43]' is invalid for input of size 660

Is there any way to add more classes to the pretrained model?

it seems like you did not use lora_config to generate a PeftModel, and if you do not want to retrain the whole model, you need change the num_labels parameter and either

use a PeftModel instead of the BertForSequenceClassification,
or freeze the base bert model and only train the classifier by,

